# Background images outside of <body>?

Tags: css, html, background, position, element

I am attempting to position a background image so that it lines up with an existing gradient background, which is relatively positioned to the `<html>` element (ie. the gradient image appears at 92% of the browser width, no matter how you size the window).

I did it by placing the image inside a `<div>`, positioning the image relative to the `<div>`, and positioning the `<div>` relative to the browser window.

eg.

```
<body>
  <div id="background-position-container">
    <img src="images/bubbles.png" id="background-corner-decoration" />
  </div>
</body>
```

with:

```
<style>
#background-position-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  top: 180px;
  left: 92%;
}

#background-corner-decoration {
  position: relative;
  /* tweak the position of the image so it lines up with the gradient */
  top: -176px;
  left: -118px;
  width: 216px;
  height: 477px;
  margin: 0px -118px -176px 0px;
}
</style>
```

This seems to work well, but if you shrink the browser window horizontally, the background image will cause the `<body>` element to grow beyond the `<html>`element, and scrollbars appear.

I seem to be able to fix this by creating a new sibling element of `<body>` and placing the `<div>` inside that:

```
<div id="background-page-container">
  <div id="background-position-container">
    <img src="images/bubbles.png" id="background-corner-decoration" />
  </div>
</div>
<body>
</body>
```

and adding:

```
#background-page-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This works in Firefox at least, but this does not seem like a good practice and I'm sure all browsers do not render this properly.  Is there a better way to accomplish what I want while leaving all display elements inside `<body>` (That is, having the background image clipped at the edge of `<body>` instead of growing it)?

Thanks for your help,
gs.

Edit: As requested, here are jsfiddles to illustrate the problem:

1. Here is what it looks like with Hiigaran's solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kn36A/
2. Here is a solution that aligns properly, but causes unsightly scrollbars when the window is re-sized: http://jsfiddle.net/w446Q/
3. Here is the "best" (?) solution I have so far, but it seems to violate HTML best-practices: http://jsfiddle.net/H2PLr/

Every browser I have tested #3 with seems to render it properly so far - is this solution really as bad as I think it is?

Thanks again!
gs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments of the other answer Hiigaran solved the problem by simply starting with solution #3 and moving the outer containing div (called "background-page-container") under <body>.  So there's no need for elements to appear outside of <body> as I had thought.

gs.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I read correctly...

You can combine background CSS by separating them with commas. So for instance, if you want to have an image and a gradient as the background for the same thing, try:

```
background-image: url('image.png'), linear-gradient(#bb0000, #0000bb);
```

You can then add other background CSS properties like `background-position` in the same manner:

```
background-position:50px 50px, 0;
```

The order of the values matters. The first set of values (50px 50px) applies to the image, but not to the gradient. The second `background-position` value (0) applies to the second `background-image` value, which is the gradient.

Using this on your HTML, you should be able to position your image with absolute or relatively values.

EDIT: Also, if you add any additional background property without commas, then the value you provide will apply to all backgrounds. For example, `background-repeat:no-repeat` will not repeat either the image or the gradient, but `background-repeat:no-repeat,repeat` will be applied to each in the same way that the position values are.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  The problem in this case is that the gradient is positioned relatively at 92% of the width of the browser.  If I position the image as a background at 92%, it will not line up properly with the gradient.  Even if I tweak the position of the image so it does line up, all you'd need to do is resize the browser window and the image will no longer line up with the gradient.  So I need a way to position the image so that it never moves relative to the position of the gradient.

Comment: See edit in original post.  Btw I was wrong about background images moving relative to the gradient if they are set to the same % position, but this happens if you attempt to line them up by positioning the two elements at different % positions (eg. 92% for gradient but 93.45% for image).

Comment: This seemed a little too easy to be the solution, but in case it is, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/H2PLr/1/ All I did was take the code from the third fiddle you linked, and put the div that was outside the body into it. Doing a side by side comparison with zooming, it appears to do exactly what you want it to do...I think.

Comment: Wow ... you are right!  I don't quite understand why that works (I thought putting it in body would cause the containing div to become the width of body instead of html), but it does! :)  Thanks so much for your help!